# How to display scraped items across multiple lines in output.log?

Tags: python, scrapy

When I use scrapy with the command `scrapy crawl my-spider --logfile=output.log`, I get items and their logs without any problems. But the way they are displayed is quite displeasing to my eyes.

**What I get:**

```
...
2020-02-26 16:23:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://some-url.com>
{'key_1': 'value_1', 'key_2': 'value_2', 'key_3': 'value_3'}
...
```

**What I want:**

```
...
2020-02-26 16:23:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://some-url.com>
{'key_1': 'value_1',
 'key_2': 'value_2',
 'key_3': 'value_3'}
...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of Scrapy are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0 right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can configure Scrapy to use your own *log formatter***, which will extend [the standard formatter](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/f558df2558966f028f773307cd5ae39a2d59e57a/scrapy/logformatter.py#L73) and **format the payload before dumping it** into the log.

As an example, let's consider the example project [quotesbot](https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot) mentioned in [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/examples.html).

[Scrapy docs say](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) there's a setting we can use:

> **LOG_FORMATTER**
>
> *Default: `scrapy.logformatter.LogFormatter`*
>
> The class to use for formatting log messages for different actions.

So, in the `settings.py` file you add a line which will tell Scrapy which *log formatter* should be used.

```
BOT_NAME = 'quotesbot'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['quotesbot.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'quotesbot.spiders'
...
...
...
LOG_FORMATTER = 'quotesbot.my_pretty_formatter.MyPrettyFormatter'  # Add this line.
```

Then create the new "pretty formatter" at `./quotesbot/my_pretty_formatter.py`:

```
from pprint import pformat
from scrapy.logformatter import LogFormatter

class MyPrettyFormatter(LogFormatter):
    def scraped(self, item, response, spider):
        pretty_item = pformat(item)  # This will prettify the item that's about to be logged.
        return super().scraped(pretty_item, response, spider)
```

**And that's it.**

Output of standard *log formatter*:

```
2020-02-26 19:57:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/10/>
{'text': '“... a mind needs books as a sword needs a whetstone, if it is to keep its edge.”', 'author': 'George R.R. Martin', 'tags': ['books', 'mind']}
```

Output of our new *pretty formatter*:

```
2020-02-26 19:55:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/10/>
{'author': 'George R.R. Martin',
 'tags': ['books', 'mind'],
 'text': '“... a mind needs books as a sword needs a whetstone, if it is to '
         'keep its edge.”'}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to use a replace after saving your log file:

```py
fin = open("output.log", "rt")
data = fin.read()
data = data.replace(', ', ',\t')
fin.close()

fin = open("output.log", "wt")
fin.write(data)
fin.close()
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that my script takes a long time to run, and format it afterward adds no value. Sorry